# react-native-router-flux Several clone

Tags: reactjs

I have a scene and i need to duplicate this scene as many times as the user need.

So i add "**clone**" property to my Scene.

```
   <Scene
                            initial={false}
                            navBar={NavBar}
                            component={MyComponent}
                            hideNavBar={false}                               
                            key='MyComponent'
                            title={('App')}
                            back
                            clone
                        />
```

And in my component {MyComponent} i have a button to duplicate this component

```
  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => Actions.MyComponent()}                       
                    <MIcon name="skip-next" size={24} color="#FFF"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

but its working only one time...

Comment: are You solved this issue? if yes so How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a paremeter in Actions, like:

```js
Actions.MyComponent({ randomParam: randomValue })
```